# The Desktop has suddenly disappeared from my Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, desktop

Man, do I hate when weird, mysterious, obscure bugs insists to randomly strike when you're expecting them the least. (1)

I turned on my personal computer this evening, only to face this:

[image: no desktop on windows 10]

**That's it. No desktop.**

Every single program I invoke runs in fullscreen mode. Including the Calculator (and it's awful). Their windows have no minimize and restore buttons, only the close button.

Right-clicking what was supposed to be the taskbar reveals these three options:

[image: right click on taskbar]

Which suggests me that maybe Windows thinks I'm on a tablet. And I'm certainly not.

A few troubleshooting points:

- It's a rather standard Windows 10 (ver 10240) installation, SSD-based, Bitlocker enabled. Windows Defender disabled by group policy. It has worked well for more than a year.
- The system was last turned off this morning, via `shutdown /s /t 0` (I do that once every a few days to keep everything fresh).
- I don't have the habit of using system cleaning tools, such as CCleaner. Definitely not related.
- `explorer.exe` is running, and so is `dwm.exe`. Windows explorer can be invoked by <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and works - but it's unusually slow.
- Restarting the OS didn't fix it.
- It also happens in Safe Mode.
- Nothing unusual in Task Scheduler, or in the Startup entries.
- It might be malware. I ran [this utility](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/36cca38cbe75a5d6d78346dce39c7df2b7ff36f0e56a931f8d529ed222794265/analysis/) earlier yesterday, and I don't use any antivirus at all (only used Outpost Firewall/Hips, but it's license expired). It was an act of imprudence, I know. But a preliminary analysis using Sandboxie didn't reveal anything wrong with that file.

<s>Just what the heck is going on</s> **Can someone shed a light on this puzzle?**

---

New details:

- When I open the Task Manager `Detail` tab, two instances of `dllhost` show up, and then disappear in a matter of seconds. It happens everytime. The instances always have different PIDs.
- A similar thing happens in Process Hacker x64 - but only for the first time it's launched. And only one `dllhost` instance, instead of two.
- I created a new Administrator account, logged in, and the desktop is normal in there.
- "Use Start full screen" is disabled in Windows 10 Personalization Settings.
- <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + clicking "Desktop" does nothing.

(1) [See here for another example](https://superuser.com/questions/1074320/google-search-results-greyed-out-on-firefox) (yet to be unraveled).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the **"Tablet Mode"** Feature in Windows 10. You might have accidentally clicked it and simply need to switch back to **"Desktop Mode"**

Click the Notification Button on the right bottom corner, then deselect "Tablet mode". A Screenshot is given for help.

[image: See the screenshot]

Comment: Awesome! (Still a mistery though, I didn't click that by any chance). Thank you